# Swift WKWebView not injecting global handler into website

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send some data from a website to my app. I've set some alert to tell me if the window.webkit.messageHandlers does exist or not, and it always tells me that it doesn't exist

ContentView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "my website url")!))
    }
}


struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    let controller: WVController = WVController()


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let jsEventHandler = "jsEventHandler"
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(controller, name: jsEventHandler)

        configuration.userContentController = contentController
        configuration.preferences = preferences

        controller.testing(str: "asd")
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

WebView.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import WebKit
//
class WVController: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        guard let response = message.body as? String else { return }
        print(response)
        print("JOHN")
    }
    func testing(str: String){
        print(str)
    }
}
```

website js - don't judge, needed something quick

```js
function send(){
    var exists = 1;
    if(!window.wekbit)
        exists = 2;
    else {
        if(!window.wekbit.messageHandlers)
            exists = 3;
        else {
            if(!window.wekbit.messageHandlers.jsEventHandler)
                exists = 4;
            else {
                if(!window.wekbit.messageHandlers.jsEventHandler.postMessage)
                    exists = 5
            }
        }
    }

    printMessage("EXISTS " + exists)
}
```

the "asd" strings does log - for testing purposes

on the website when i call send() it always prints "2", so window.webkit does not exist

I'm new to swift and all tutorials i find are with ViewController.swift, but I don't have that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so it seems that it's actually
webkit.messageHandlers.jsEventHandler.postMessage()

without "window." prefix

Comment: If this solved your question don't forget to mark it as the answer. It will help other users.